# Only first fragment is drawn correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin

I have an activity called `Session` which shows different tables and when the button for each table is clicked, the `Seats` should be displayed but they are only being displayed on the first table.

Session contains a List of the `Table Fragments` and each table contains a list of the `Seat Fragments`.

```
[Activity] Session
    [List<TableFragment>] Tables
        [List<SeatFragment>] Seats
```

Expected result on all tables:
[image]

How it looks on all the tables except on the first table:
[image]

Also when I enter the `Session` activity an empty table is created with the "Table Name" and the "Seats" with the name set by the `Seat Fragment` which is strange. "Table Name" is a variable taken from the layout file so that is okay but the buttons are created programatically so they should not be in that "empty" fragment. The "Table Name" text is being displayed correctly on all the different `Table Fragments` so I'm pretty sure it has something to do with when I'm creating the `Seat Fragments` but I don't know what it might be. All the tags are different and the first table works like a charm.
[image]

In `Session` I have a method to create the tables and at the same time I create the seats. I first thought it had something to do with the Commit taking some time so I moved it out from CreateTables but with the same result:

```
private void CreateTables()
        {
            try
            {
                tables = new List<Fragments.Session.Table>();
                foreach (var table in A.ActiveSession.Tables)
                {
                    FragmentTransaction trans = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    var frag = new Fragments.Session.Table();
                    trans.Add(Resource.Id.frameLayoutSessionTable, frag, "table-" + table.Id.ToString());
                    trans.Commit();


                    frag.CreateSeats(table.Seats);
                    tables.Add(frag);   
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Could not create tables ...", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
```

Table.CreateSeats():

```
public void CreateSeats(List<SessionSeatViewModel> _seats)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fragments.Table.CreateSeats()");

            seats = new List<Seat>();

            foreach (var seat in _seats)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Tag: " + "seat-" + seat.Id.ToString());
                var tag = "seat-" + seat.Id.ToString();
                FragmentTransaction trans = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                var frag = new Fragments.Session.Seat();
                trans.Add(Resource.Id.layoutSeats, frag, tag);
                trans.Commit();
                seats.Add(frag);
            }
        }
```

I can that the seats are being created as expected and when I call my "Table.Show()" the correct Seat ID's are being printed out into the log:

```
var activeTable = this.FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag<Fragments.Session.Table>("table-" + table.Id.ToString());
                    activeTable.Update(table); //Updates the seats with correct values
                    activeTable.Show();
```

Table.Show():

```
public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fragments.Table.Show()");
            this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Show(this).Commit();
            foreach (var seat in seats)
                seat.Show();
        }
```

Seat.Show():

```
public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fragments.Session.Seat.Show()");
            this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Show(this).Commit();
        }
```

I also tried `this.FragmentManager.ExecutePendingTransactions()` after I created each table and before `CreateSeats` with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Nested Fragments we need to use the ChildFragmentManager.

This is how I solved it in Xamarin:

Under `Session` I create the tables as before:

```
private void CreateTables()
        {
            try
            {
                tables = new List<Fragments.Session.Table>();
                var trans = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                foreach (var table in A.ActiveSession.Tables)
                {
                    var tag = "table-" + table.Id.ToString();
                    var frag = new Fragments.Session.Table();
                    trans.Add(Resource.Id.frameLayoutSessionTable, frag, tag);
                    tables.Add(frag);
                    if (mCurrentFragment == null) mCurrentFragment = frag;
                    else trans.Hide(frag);
                }
                trans.Commit();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Could not create tables ...", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
```

Under `Table.OnCreateView` I create the `Seat` fragments using the `ChildFragmentManager` (the fixed size is just temporary):

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Table.OnCreateView");
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.table_session, container, false);

            mText = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewTableSessionName);

            var trans = ChildFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            seats = new List<Seat>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {

                var frag = new Fragments.Session.Seat();
                trans.Add(Resource.Id.layoutSeats, frag, "seat-" + (i+1).ToString());
                seats.Add(frag);
            }
            trans.Commit();

            return view;
        }
```

`Session` inherits from `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment`, `Table` and `Seat` from `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment`.

I found the answer under this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wEGeT3zg6I&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l&index=62
(Check Tutorial 55 and 56 if you don't understand).